# How to restore local login on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird

I recently upgraded to windows 10 home from 8.1 I had a local login and added added a microsoft account and a pin. I tried to remove the pin and ended up not being able to reset my password.

I have other local admin accounts. So I removed the microsoft account (probably a *big* mistake). My user data is still there.

All of my personal data except email is on another disk. My thunderbird profiles are unfortunately in c:/User/ray/. Fooling around with Profile.ini does not seem to help and import does not find anything.

Ideally I would be able to get the local login to work. Getting tbird to work would be almost as good.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Edit @harrymc's idea worked fine. tbird just came up with all of my email.

Creating a new account with the same name created a different folder: c:/Users/ray.machine-name looks like i did not lose anything accept .ini files and cached data. So now i just have a different login name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple to transfer Thunderbird profiles - I have done this many times.

You need to find your two Thunderbird profile folders - the old and new.
Both will reside in a folder named
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles`.
The profile folder itself is a sub-folder of this one and its name looks like
`somestring.default`.

Once you have found both `.default` folders, delete the **contents** of the new folder
(assuming that it doesn't contain any useful data),
then copy into it the **contents** of the old folder.

Starting Thunderbird, you should now find that you have all your old accounts and data.